# Redirecionar url post HTTP para HTTPS no nginx

Tags: http, post, nginx, https

Tenho uma aplicação que recebo POSTS de retorno do sistema de pagamentos, mas atualmente forçamos o uso do SSL para nosso site, fiz o redirecionamento HTTP para HTTPS, porém recebo erro 404 quando o sistema do POSTBACK envia o POST para a URL http://...., quando meu servidor tenta redirecionar para HTTPS( Ou não tenta ) aparece o erro 404.

Arquivo NGNIX:

```
# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/magicaonline.com.br/before/*;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 307 https://magicaonline.com.br/$1;
}

server {
    listen 443 http2;
    listen [::]:443 http2;
    server_name .magicaonline.com.br;
    root /home/forge/magicaonline.com.br/public;

    if ($host = 'www.magicaonline.com.br') {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://magicaonline.com.br/$1 permanent;
    }

    #if ($scheme = http) {
    #    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    #}

    # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/magicaonline.com.br/132754/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/magicaonline.com.br/132754/server.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers 'xxxxx';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
    include forge-conf/magicaonline.com.br/server/*;

    location /lp/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
    }

    location @wordpress {
        rewrite /lp/ /lp/index.php;
    }

    location ^/lp/index.php(/.*)?$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/lp/index.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/magicaonline.com.br-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

# FORGE CONFIG (DOT NOT REMOVE!)
include forge-conf/magicaonline.com.br/after/*;
```

Há possibilidades de fazer isso acontecer ?

Preciso dessa solução por que o sistema de pagamentos não aceita modificar a URL do POSTBACK.

Answer (score 1):

O 302 transforma seu POST num GET, o próprio browser executa esse comportamento.

Seguindo a recomendação do Joao, que está correta, temos um case simples:

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                           '"$request" - "$request_body" - $status $body_bytes_sent '
                           '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$gzip_ratio"';

    server {
        listen       8181;
        server_name  localhost;

        access_log /my_path/log/nginx.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass_header on;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/receive;
        }
    }

    include servers/*;
}
```

Aqui temos um servidor ouvindo a porta 8181, com escrita de log ativada. Ao realizar um post simples usando curl nessa rota:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"product": "New product", "id": "1"}' http://localhost:81
```

A requisição será redirecionada para a porta 8080, mantendo os headers. Para testar podemos criar um servidor nodejs ouvindo essa porta:

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var url = require('url')
var app = express()

app.post('/receive', function(request, respond) {
    var body = ''

    filePath = __dirname + '/post.txt'
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data
    })

    request.on('end', function (){
        body = body + '\n'
        fs.appendFile(filePath, body, function() {
            respond.end()
        })
    })
})

app.listen(8080)
```

Para executar o servidor node é só usar os comandos:

```
npm init
npm install --save express
node index.js
```

Esse servidor recebe o redirecionamento do nginx e escreve o post num arquivo chamado post.txt.

Ao realizar todo o processo teremos como entrada nesse arquivo:

```
{"product": "New product", "id": "1"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade, segundo a [spec do HTTP](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), o user-agent 302 não deve redirecionar a request inteira. Acredito que o que aconteça é que a sua request, quando chega o 302, se torna um `GET`, e isso causa o seu 404 (já que provavelmente o server só está esperando um `POST`).

Acho que o ideal seria você utilizar uma função de [reverse-proxy do Nginx chamad a Proxy Pass](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Atualizar o seu redirecionamento para:

```
if ($scheme = http) {
  proxy_pass_header on;
  proxy_pass https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

pode resolver seu problema. A primeira linha ativa o envio dos headers, que vão ser necessários pro seu POSTback e vem desabilitados por padrão, e a segunda define a url pro proxy.

Comment: João, primeiramente obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Infelizmente não conseguir fazer funcionar, pode me dar um exemplo dentro dentro do arquivo que está acima ?